# How to use GetX Navigation from a Page to itself with different controllers

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-navigation

I am using Getx MVC and named routing, I want to navigate to the same page again and create new controller.

I made the **preventDuplicates** as false which is letting me open the same page again, but it is showing same data. I want to create a new controller with tag everytime the page gets opened

```
Future<void> openMemberDetails(MemberData data) async {
    await Get.toNamed(Routes.MEMBER_DETAILS, arguments: data, preventDuplicates: false);
}
```

```
class MemberDetailsView extends GetView<MemberDetailsController> {
  const MemberDetailsView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller.context = context;
    return Scaffold(
    ///
    );
  }
}
```

```
class MemberDetailsController extends GetxController with GetTickerProviderStateMixin {
  MemberData memberData = Get.arguments as MemberData;
  final apiHelper = Get.find<ApiHelper>();
  late BuildContext context;
  ///
  Future<void> openMemberDetails(MemberData data) async {
    await Get.toNamed(Routes.MEMBER_DETAILS, arguments: data, preventDuplicates: false);
  }
}
```